# How do I give axios interceptors access to my react app's state?

Tags: reactjs, axios, interceptor

I am using an axios interceptor to handle errors globally, but would like to set the state of my app from the interceptor. Something like:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
   error => {
      AppState.setError(error)
   }
)

function App() {

   [error,setError] = useState()

}
```

How can I either access the state of App from outside, or alternatively how can I call a function defined within App from the interceptor?

I've tried

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
   error => {
      App.setAppErrorState(error)
   }
)

function App() {

   this.setAppErrorState = function(error) {
       // do something with error like set it to state
   }

}
```

but get the error "TypeError: Cannot set property 'setAppErrorState' of undefined"

I'm not currently using Redux so a solution without using it would be preferable. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about setting the interceptor inside the `App` component ?

```js
function App() {
  const [error, setError] = useState();

  useMemo(() => {
    axios.interceptors.response.use(
      error => {
        setError(error)
      }
    )
  }, [setError])


}
```

---

***Notice*** (*quote from https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo*)

> **You may rely on `useMemo` as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee**. In the future, React may choose to “forget” some previously memoized values and recalculate them on next render, e.g. to free memory for offscreen components. Write your code so that it still works without `useMemo` — and then add it to optimize performance.

Comment: Thank you. Such an obvious solution and I thought I had exhausted this option but apparently always put the interceptor inside the useEffect() function which stopped it working for all child components.

Comment: @EdwardMartin `useEffect` is executed after the render/mount of the component so all of its children need to have been mounted as well. This means that on initial run they will not have the interceptor set. See [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-water-5dmk9?file=/src/App.js) example i made to showcase it (*see the order in the console log*).

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Just want to mention that function passed to `useMemo` can be executed more than once even if dep. don't change, but I suppose won't do much harm in this case.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava good warning. I will add the official disclaimer in the answer.

Comment: Hm and [according](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useMemo#parameters) to react beta docs the function which you pass to `useMemo` should be *pure*, and IMHO the one above isn't pure.